# the select query based on inner join doesn´t work, returns nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, inner-join, where-clause

I have the code below that does not return any values when it should. Is there anyone that can find anything faulty with it? When I run the script I get 0 values in return (0 rows affected), even though I know that there are rows that should be selected.

This is just a part of the whole script, and when I run everything I get the error message "Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation". But I don´t know what this implies for my script. I only have 1 "group by" in the script (which I don´t post here since that coding works). Does anyone know?

The code, below, should create a temp-table and to the temp-table insert rows from the table "StatusHistorik" where the following conditions are met:

1) [NyStatus]=4 (NyStatus is a column from the table "StatusHistorik"),

2) The variable "EnhetsId" should not exist in the table "SKL_AdminKontroll_SkaÅtgärdas" (F). Code: "F.EnhetsId is null".

I have used inner joins in both cases. This should result in a number of observations/rows in the temp-table, but returns nothing. Does anyone find any errors with the coding that could explain the absent of result?

I should mention that when I "comment away" the last inner join and the last part of the where-statement, the script works as it is supposed to. So I suspect that it is the last inner join-statement that is wrong somehow.

```
declare @temp2 table (
   EnhetsId varchar(50), 
   TjanstId Int, 
   Tabell varchar(50),
   Kommentar ntext,
   Uppdaterad datetime
);
WITH ENHET_AVSLUT AS 
(
        SELECT DISTINCT A.[EnhetsId]
        FROM [StatistikinlamningDataSKL].[dbo].[StatusHistorik] A
        inner join (
                 select [EnhetsId], max(SenastUppdaterad) as SenastDatum
                 from [StatistikinlamningDataSKL].[dbo].[StatusHistorik]
                 group by [EnhetsId]
                 ) B
        on A.[EnhetsId] = B.[EnhetsId] and A.[SenastUppdaterad] = B.SenastDatum
        INNER JOIN
                 StatistikinlamningDataSKL.dbo.SKL_AdminKontroll_SkaÅtgärdas F ON A.EnhetsId = F.EnhetsId
        WHERE [NyStatus] = 4 AND F.EnhetsId is null
)
insert into @temp2  
    (EnhetsId, TjanstId, Tabell, Kommentar, Uppdaterad) 
SELECT 
    EnhetsId, 1, ''GR_PS09_1'', ''OK'', getdate() 
from ENHET_AVSLUT

select * from @temp2
```

Best regards,
Hannes

Comment: Use LEFT OUTER JOIN for the table SKL_AdminKontroll_SkaÅtgärdas.

Comment: THANKS!! It solved the problem. Although, I noticed that the full script still does not work, I think, due to the error message:Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
Do you have any idea on that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are saying

```
The variable "EnhetsId" should not exist in the table "SKL_AdminKontroll_SkaÅtgärdas" (F). Code: "F.EnhetsId is null".
```

an INNER JOIN will try to join the tables and will not be able to perform a JOIN on NULL values, so the result will be zero rows.

So you must try using LEFT JOIN, where the tables ON LEFT will be pulled irrespective of the JOIN condition being satisfied.

I must warn you though, if the table is large it might have performance issues.

Your inner SQL must be something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.[EnhetsId]
    FROM [StatistikinlamningDataSKL].[dbo].[StatusHistorik] A
    inner join (
             select [EnhetsId], max(SenastUppdaterad) as SenastDatum
             from [StatistikinlamningDataSKL].[dbo].[StatusHistorik]
             group by [EnhetsId]
             ) B
    on A.[EnhetsId] = B.[EnhetsId] and A.[SenastUppdaterad] = B.SenastDatum
    LEFT JOIN
             StatistikinlamningDataSKL.dbo.SKL_AdminKontroll_SkaÅtgärdas F ON A.EnhetsId = F.EnhetsId
    WHERE [NyStatus] = 4
```

Comment: You´re right, a left join is the correct way. But I still need the "AND F.EnhetsId is null" to avoid those not in the table "SKL_AdminKontroll_SkaÅtgärdas"

Comment: @user2995808 Right, adding F.EnhetsID IS NULL will exclude those in table F, it's equivalent to WHERE NOT EXISTS (...select in F WHERE your join predicates .. ) see http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=QueryBasedUponAbsenceOfData